# About the Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

In my app, I overwrited the `onPause()` function, however, it didn't work, and `onStop()` was still invoked. Any advice is appreciated, thx!

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        if(the activity did not meet my requirements)
            this.onResume();
        else
            super.onPause();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not directly call `onResume()` or `onPause();.` They are callback methods and are invoked by system.

Comment: You can call them just like any other method.  The difference is, you *shouldn't* call them.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to prevent the system from pausing your application because whenever that method is invoked it means the user doesn't want to use your application right now.  That reason could be a phone call is starting, switching to another app, backing out, etc.  Android is still going to think your application is paused and do what it wants (and designed to do) with it.  A better solution would be to save whatever state your application is in on `onPause()`, then restore the state in `onResume()` if/when the user comes back.